# How to make wordpress widget container full width

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, plugins

I built a plugin to display a full page tab after you call the shortcode.
This is how it looks when I run it.
[image: Full page tab]
When I installed it however this is how it looks
[image: Wordpress full page tab]

As you can see not only is the tab not a full page, the tabs stylesheet has managed to affect the entire site and disorganized it.
I want to make the tab full width(from one end of the page to another) and I want the style for the plugin to only affect the slider returned by the plugin.
I use elementor page builder and I've tried setting the elementor container's margin to 0. It reduced the space but it's still not enough as you can see from the image. My site's layout is already set to 100% full-width. I would appreciate any help I can get.
Here's the CSS for the plugin below.

```css
.elementor-container {
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.bs-example {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.hide23 {
  border-style: none !important;
}

.tab-pane {
  margin: 20px;
}

.selected {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FF7F50;
}

@media screen and (min-device-width: 300px) {
  .tab-content {
    width: 50% !important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  /*  li {width:50%;}*/
  ul {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 959px) {
  .elementor-container {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  .elementor-column-gap-default {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: black;
}

a {
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

ul:hover {
  color: transparent!important;
}

ul {
  border-style: none !important;
  /*border-bottom: 2px solid #FF7F50  !important;*/
}

{
  display: inline !important;
  color: black;
}

.span-active {
  border: 2px solid #FF7F50;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #FF7F50;
}

.span-inactive {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  color: grey !important;
  background-color: white;
}

.inactive {
  color: grey !important;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: #FF7F50;
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else. I apologize if the answer is obvious. I'm new to WordPress development

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on the WordPress SE

Comment: there's an option for full-width in the edit widget thing no? (used to using SiteOrigins so may differ...)?

Comment: Please provide screenshot of the page or URL of the page then we can more

Comment: @ChetanKanani the screeshot of the page is provided above

Comment: @treyBake everything is already set to 100%

Comment: @Drownedgod is that one of the options? For me I get stuff like: full-width, centre-columned etc.